# An XSD element can contains a bool value or an attribute?

Tags: xml, soap, xsd

How can I define and xsd element that can work with both the follows soap request formats (where 'MyOption' is optional and may not be present)?

Request 1:

```
<sdf:MyElement>true</sdf:MyElement>
```

or

Request 2:

```
<sdf:MyElement>
    <sdf:MyOption>xxx</sdf:MyOption>
    <sdf:Value>true</sdf:Value>
</<sdf:MyElement>
```

I tried with this, but it work only with Request 2 format:

```
<xs:element name="MyElement" default="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
            <xs:attribute name="MyOption" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
         </xs:extension>
       </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: In your Request 2 the `MyElement` has two child elements, but no attribute. The schema snippet you have shown does not describe that structure at all, instead it would describe `<MyElement MyOption="foo">true</MyElement>`. A schema for the second Request sample would need to define the two child elements in a `sequence` of a `complexType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that this is not a strict answer to your question but I have to point this out. There is a reason that creating such an element is not easy in the wsdl schema.

It really does not seem like sensible service contract design to make both options available. It is against the principles of SOA Service design, so I advise strongly against it. Here is why:

- It will probably confuse consumers and developers to start with;
- It harms service discoverability because it impairs contract interpretability- this element would have a *variable* type and behaves differently in some scenarios - sometimes it expects child elements, sometimes it expects inner text value;
- This type will not have proper validation logic generated automatically - you will have to implement a specific validation logic that covers both scenarios.

My advise - stick only to some form of the Request 2 format and leave the Option optional. I would do this by just adding a simple sequence of elements as Martin Honnen points out in his comment.